# Запуск бинарника в php

Tags: php, c++, linux

Всем привет! Подскажите, как запустить бинарник при помощи php? И вообще, есть ли какое-нибудь взаимодействие между php и cpp?

Comment: system() не? или exec...

Answer (score 6):

`proc_open` — Выполняет команду и открывает указатель на файл для ввода/вывода (Фукнция `proc_open` специфична только для юникс систем)
`resource proc_open ( string $cmd , array $descriptorspec , array &$pipes [, string $cwd [, array $env [, array $other_options ]]] )`.

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin - канал, из которого дочерний процесс будет читать
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout - канал, в который дочерний процесс будет записывать 
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr - файл для записи
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes теперь выглядит так:
    // 0 => записывающий обработчик, подключенный к дочернему stdin
    // 1 => читающий обработчик, подключенный к дочернему stdout
    // Вывод сообщений об ошибках будет добавляться в /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // Важно закрывать все каналы перед вызовом
    // proc_close во избежание мертвой блокировки
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "команда вернула $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [some_option] => aeiou
    [PWD] => /tmp
    [SHLVL] => 1
    [_] => /usr/local/bin/php
)
команда вернула 0
```

system — Выполняет внешнюю программу и отображает её вывод
string system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )
пример

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

// Выводит весь результат шелл-команды "ls", и возвращает 
// последнюю строку вывода в переменной $last_line. Сохраняет код возврата
// шелл-команды в $retval.
$last_line = system('ls', $retval);

// Выводим дополнительную информацию
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Последняя строка вывода: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Код возврата: ' . $retval;
?>
```

Comment: Хм, вот я пытаюсь запустить файл "bin" к примеру, так и не понял куда его привинтить? system('bin', $retval); system('./bin', $retval); не работает, или я не туда привинтил?

Comment: У сервера своё окружение (см. переменную PATH), и свой текущий каталог. Возможно, system() просто не находит файл, можно попробовать запустить с полным путём. Потом, запуск может быть банально запрещён (см. safe_mode, safe_mode_exec_dir и т.д.)

Comment: Ни когда не подумал бы, что вызвать бинарник в пхп такая проблема. Так в php.ini изменил строчку safe_mode_exec_dir = "/home/karr/php_bin", ковычки так и не понял нужны или нет. Далее всему чему можно и не можно дал 777 права, осталось наверное только корень рекурсивно чмоднуть 777 правами. Запускаю так $last_line = system('/home/karr/php_bin/test', $retval); или вообще как правильно бинарник запустить? в консоле я так запускаю - "./name" а тут я хз...Руками из той папки запустил - бинарник работает. Что делать в конце концов не знаю.

Comment: Да, не влезло все. Как быть с параметрами safe_mode = Off, safe_mode_gid = Off, safe_mode_include_dir = , и как вообще правильно указывать пути с кавычками или без? ох уж этот веб, помнится как-то апач ковырял, было что-то похожее, ковычки не поставил где они чисто логически не каким образом стоять не могли, он и не заводился. Ладно, это уже как говорится другая история.

Comment: Права на исполнение бинарника выставил?
chmod +x test.bin
Прав на каталог достаточно 755
>How Should I set my file permissions on cgi-scripts?
>Executed via the web by anyone: chmod 755

Comment: Что значит "код возврата - 1" ?

Comment: Копипаста конечноже, http://www.php.su/proc_open , описание дурное..